# How do I handle DB connections on HTTP requests?

Tags: rethinkdb

Do I open and close a connection to a RethinkDB server on every HTTP request? I was reading a [tutorial of the official examples](http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/examples/node-todo/). It describes an Express app and it basically looks like:

```
var app = express();
app.use(openConnection);
app.use(/* do stuff */);
app.use(closeConnection);
```

Is this considered best practice or is this the only practice since there is no native connection pooling or other approaches?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to how to deal with connections, there are a couple of options:

**Single Connection**

The simplest option is to just open a single connection and use it through out your app. This is extremely simple but probably doesn't work for larger applications where you might be executing a lot of requests.

In JavaScript, the connection can be appended to the `r` object and used throughout the application.

```
import r from 'rethinkdb';
import express from 'express';

let app = express();

r.connect().then((conn) => {
   r.conn = conn;
});

app.use('/table-list', (req, res) => {
  r.db('test').tableList().run(conn)
    .then((result) => {
      return res.json(result);    
    });
});
```

**Open & Close**

You can also just open and close a connection every single time you do a request. This approach is also simple, but it's a bit more verbose.

```
r.connect().then((conn) => 
  return r.db('test').tableList().run(conn)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);    
      return result;
    })
    .then(() => {
      conn.close();
    });
});
```

**Per Request Connection**

As you noted earlier, you can also open a connection per-request, use that connection throughout the request, and then close it when the request is done.

**Connection Pooling**

Finally, you can also use connection pooling if you use [rethinkdbdash](https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash), which abstracts away connections for you.

Comment: Personally I do not mind opening and closing on each request. But I am very used to connection pools and I read this is the de facto best practice on how to handle db connections.
I am not a Coffeescript expert, but how is the `conn` variable in your single connection example accessible in the use function?

Comment: It would be attached to the rethinkdb singleton (`r`). That's why, once connected, I do `r.conn = conn`.

Comment: You'd need to be careful with this, because you don't want to run any queries before getting the connection.

Comment: If you feel you *really* want to have a connection pool, just use rethinkdbdash. :)

Comment: But still, you should use `r.conn` in your `run()` function and not `conn` then, right?

Comment: You should only use the `r.conn` if you only want to have a single connection for your whole app.